# Упорядоченное множество

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
h = [9, 8, 7, 4, 5, 6, 3, 2, 1, 5, 5]
new_h = {x*2 for x in h}
```

Почему при генерации множество получается упорядоченное по возрастанию?
Оно же вроде рандомное и без индексации

Comment: Похоже для ваших данных случайно так получается. Возможно причина в какой-то оптимизации для маленьких чисел. Добавьте в свой массив 20, например, и множество будет уже неупорядоченным.

Comment: У этой случайности есть объяснение.

Comment: Я удивляюсь вашей наблюдательности. Браво!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это особенность реализации `set`. Хеш коды неотрицательных целых чисел до 2<sup>61</sup> - 2 равны самим этим числам.

Если заполнять хешсет последовательно с меньших чисел до больших, они станут занимать последовательные корзины. Номер корзины вычисляется как хеш код по модулю текущей вместимости хешсет. А вместимость в этой ситуации больше любого хешкода. Итерация ведётся по корзинам, получаем упорядоченное множество. Если порядок заполнения другой, в процессе заполнения порядок хешсета может быть произвольным, но после последнего rehashing (как это будет по-русски?) элементы в хешсет снова займут последовательные корзины. Потому что все их хешкоды меньше вместимости и совпадают с самими числами.

**P.S.** Никогда не используйте в программировании это случайное свойство хешсетов последовательных целых чисел. Реализация и хешсета и хешкодов целых чисел может быть изменена и упорядоченность исчезнет. Никаких гарантий тут быть не может.

**P.P.S.** Ответ предполагает что вы знаете как устроен хешсет. Если нет, пишите комментарии. Тема занятная.

**P.P.P.S.** Зная как распределяются числа по корзинам легко придумать множества чисел на которых производительность `set` будет деградировать. :(

Comment: Вы пишите, "А вместимость в этой ситуации больше любого хешкода.", но `h = [20, 10, 9, 8, 7, 4, 5, 6, 3, 2, 1]; new_h = {x*2 for x in h}; print(new_h); new_h` выдаёт упорядоченный результат только в `ipython` и только оператором `new_h`. Есть тому объяснение?

Comment: @Serge3leo . Почитал реализацию `set` в CPython. Да, есть. Окончательное множество - 11 элементов. Размер выделенного массива будет - 32. Если вы возьмёте любые 11 чисел в диапазоне [0, 31] они окажутся упорядочены. В вашем примере есть элемент - 40. Здесь как повезёт.

Comment: @Serge3leo, зато можно предсказать что 8 и 40 в итерации множества из 11 элементов всегда будут рядом (если между ними не встрянут другие числа вида 8 + 32k).

Comment: На мой взгляд, более примечательно, что, как минимум, в ipython 8.2.0 на основе python 3.6.10, операторы `print(new_h); new_h` выдают разный результат.

Comment: @Serge3leo, это для меня полная загадка. Я могу догадаться что ipython меняет процедуры вывода. Это может коснуться как print так и просто печати переменной. В такой ситуации будет правильно печатать `tuple(new_h)` (если мы интересуемся именно устройством `set` а не вводом/выводом ipython).

Answer (score 4):

Нет, оно не получается упорядоченным. Мало того, видимый порядок элемента множества может зависеть от способа взгляда на него.

```
$ python
Python 3.10.6 (main, Aug  3 2022, 03:52:09) [Clang 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> h = [9, 8, 7, 4, 5, 6, 3, 2, 1, 5, 5, 10, 20]
>>> new_h = {x*2 for x in h}
>>> print(new_h, [i for i in new_h])
{2, 4, 6, 8, 40, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20} [2, 4, 6, 8, 40, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]
>>> new_h, [i for i in new_h]
({2, 4, 6, 8, 40, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20}, [2, 4, 6, 8, 40, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20])
```

и

```
$ ipython
Python 3.10.6 (main, Aug  3 2022, 03:52:09) [Clang 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62)]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 8.2.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: h = [9, 8, 7, 4, 5, 6, 3, 2, 1, 5, 5, 10, 20]
   ...: new_h = {x*2 for x in h}
   ...: print(new_h, [i for i in new_h])
   ...: new_h, [i for i in new_h]
{2, 4, 6, 8, 40, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20} [2, 4, 6, 8, 40, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]
Out[1]: 
({2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 40},
 [2, 4, 6, 8, 40, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20])
```

P.S.

По результату дискуссии со @StanislavVolodarskiy следует отметить настройку "Pretty printing" в IPython (Jupyter Notebook и прочая, прочая), которая упорядочивает элементы множества при печати результата:

```
$ ipython 
Python 3.10.6 (main, Aug  3 2022, 03:52:09) [Clang 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62)]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 8.2.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: from random import *

In [2]: {randrange(300) for i in range(10)}
Out[2]: {4, 6, 25, 30, 68, 90, 106, 136, 146, 262}

In [3]: %pprint
Pretty printing has been turned OFF

In [4]: Out[2]
Out[4]: {4, 68, 262, 6, 136, 106, 146, 25, 90, 30}

In [5]: %pprint
Pretty printing has been turned ON

In [6]: Out[2]
Out[6]: {4, 6, 25, 30, 68, 90, 106, 136, 146, 262}
```

Comment: Кажется, вы правы про ipython. Он что-то делает с печатью переменных типа `set`. Возможно сортировка значений при выполнении `new_h` ?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy , да это "Pretty print" так работает.